# Program written in Fortran to python?

Tags: fortran, anaconda, f2py

There's a program called [GranFilm](http://web.phys.ntnu.no/~ingves/Software/GranFilm/Current/download.html)  calculating the polarizability of a sphere. I'd like to extract this value from the program. As you may guess, I have no experience with Fortran. I learned how to successfully import Fortran function but just from a single .f90 file... In the program, there's a dozen of file. I tried to list them all like indicated here: [F2py example](http://websrv.cs.umt.edu/isis/index.php/F2py_example) to no avail. I'm not sure what should be included in the command.

The polarizability is calculated in optics_mod.f90. This file uses Global_definitions.f90 & Interaction_mod.f90.

What I tried:

```
f2py -m test -h Test.py global_def.f90 optics_mod.f90 integral_mod.f90
```

What I get:

```
(base) C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\Sphere>call "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\\..\python.exe" "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\\f2py.py" -m test -h test.py global_def.f90 optics_mod.f90 integral_mod.f90
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'global_def.f90' (format:free)
        Reading file 'os.h' (format:fix)
        Reading file 'optics_mod.f90' (format:free)
        Reading file 'integral_mod.f90' (format:free)
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "type" with "type_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "type" with "type_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
rmbadname1: Replacing "int" with "int_bn".
Post-processing...
        Block: test
                        Block: global_definitions
In: :test:global_def.f90:global_definitions
get_parameters: got "invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)" on '(0.wp,1.'
                                Block: parameters
                                Block: surface_constitutive
                                Block: invariants
                                Block: mumubar
                                Block: integrals
                                Block: polynomials
                                Block: arth
                                Block: arth_sp
                                Block: arth_dp
                                Block: locate
                        Block: optics_mod
In: :test:optics_mod.f90:optics_mod
get_parameters: got "invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)" on '(0.wp,1.'
```

and then I get the same "invalid syntax" for many extra lines but it still saves to a signature file. I wonder what's the cause of that problem?

What I'd like to calculate isn't trivial so the reuse of code is pretty advantageous for my grad project. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `interaction_mod.f90` uses `legendre.f90` also, maybe add it ? And `glob_def.f90` uses `os.h`. I don't know F2py, but if the order has an importance, it may be `os.h glob_def.90 legendre.f90 interaction_mod.f90 optics_mod.f90`.